# How to fill a vector of vectors iteratively in R

Tags: r, loops

I want to create a new column in my data frame containing the name or index of all the columns that contain a value different than 0 (The data frame is filled with integer values)

The code I tried is:

```
v <- rep(NA, 3)
M <- data.frame(x1=c(1,0,0), x2=c(0,5,5), x3=c(0,0,1),
                y=c(5, 0, 0), z=c(0,0,2))

for(i in 1:nrow(M)) {
  for(j in 1:ncol(M)) {
   if(M[i,j] > 1) {v[i] <- c(v[i], j)}
  }
}
```

but I get the error:

> In v[i] <- c(cluster_DM[i], j) : number of items to replace is not a
> multiple of replacement length

The output should look like this:

```
|   x1   |   x2   |   x3   |    y   |    z   |           v         |
| ------ | ------ | ------ | ------ | ------ | ------------------- |
|    1   |    0   |    0   |    5   |    0   |      ['x1','y']     |
|    0   |    5   |    0   |    0   |    0   |        ['x2']       |
|    0   |    5   |    1   |    0   |    2   |   ['x2','x3','z']   |
```

and I know there must be a smarter way to avoid the for loops. I would be very happy about any suggestion. Thanks!

Comment: You commented _but with this solution the new raw has string values and not a vector with multiple integers_ multiple times. The answers given reproduce (imho) your expected output. Please clarify what you expect, if the answers don't satisfy your needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a `tidyverse` solution to reach your expected output ;

```
M <- data.frame(x1=c(1,0,0), x2=c(0,5,5), x3=c(0,0,1),
                y=c(5, 0, 0), z=c(0,0,2))


library(dplyr)


M %>%
rowwise %>%
mutate(v=sapply(list(colnames(.)[across(everything())!=0]),paste0,collapse=',')) %>%
ungroup
```

**output;**

```
     x1    x2    x3     y     z v      
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>  
1     1     0     0     5     0 x1,y   
2     0     5     0     0     0 x2     
3     0     5     1     0     2 x2,x3,z
```

TO GET INDEXES

```
M %>%
rowwise %>%
mutate(v=sapply(list((1:length(colnames(.)))[across(everything())!=0]),paste0,collapse=',')) %>%
ungroup
```

**output;**

```
     x1    x2    x3     y     z v    
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>
1     1     0     0     5     0 1,4  
2     0     5     0     0     0 2    
3     0     5     1     0     2 2,3,5
```

Comment: Hey Samet, thank you for your help. And how should I do if I want the last column to be a vector of the indices? As an example in the first row [0,3]?

Comment: @ncnc_2020 hi, R isn't a zero based language, I mean the first index is always 1. So, you're supposed to obtain [1,4]. to reach it change `colnames(.)` to `(1:length(colnames(.)))`

Comment: @ncnc_2020 probably a typo, I am now attaching the working code to get indexes.

Comment: But then, my new row is still from type chr, so the values are strings and not vectors with multiple integers

Comment: @ncnc_2020  because you are separating them with comma, r doesn't have that kind of data structure.

Answer (score 1):

Base R option with `apply` -

```
cols <- names(M)
M$v <- apply(M, 1, function(x) toString(cols[x != 0]))
M

#  x1 x2 x3 y z         v
#1  1  0  0 5 0     x1, y
#2  0  5  0 0 0        x2
#3  0  5  1 0 2 x2, x3, z
```

And another method using `which` and `tapply` -

```
mat <- which(M > 0, arr.ind = TRUE)
M$v <- tapply(cols[mat[, 2]], mat[, 1], toString)
```

Comment: but with this solution the new row has string values and not a vector with multiple integers

Answer (score 0):

Developing the for loop approach you were taking:

```
v <- c()

for (i in 1:nrow(M)) {
  vec <- c()
  for (j in 1:ncol(M)) {
    if (M[i,j] > 0) {vec <- c(vec, colnames(M)[j])}
  }
  if (length(vec) > 0) {
    v <- c(v, paste0(vec, collapse = ", "))
  } else {
    v <- c(v, "")
  }
}

M['v'] <- v

  x1 x2 x3 y z          v
1  1  0  0 5 0      x1, y
2  0  5  0 0 0         x2
3  0  5  1 0 2  x2, x3, z
```

Comment: but with this solution the new raw has string values and not a vector with multiple integers

Answer (score 0):

We can try `tapply` + `col`+ `row` like below

```
M$v <- tapply(names(M)[col(M)][M != 0], row(M)[M != 0], toString)
```

such that

```
> M
  x1 x2 x3 y z         v
1  1  0  0 5 0     x1, y
2  0  5  0 0 0        x2
3  0  5  1 0 2 x2, x3, z
```